# Invoking function inside a loop leads to a memory_limit exceeded

Tags: php, arrays

I am processing somewhat big sized files in PHP (300 MB - 1024 MB) in pursue of finding a line that matches my search criteria and return the whole line. Since I cannot afford to read the entire file and store it in memory, I am reading line-by-line:

```
function getLineWithString($fileName, $str) {

    $matches = array();
    $handle = @fopen($fileName, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);

            if (strpos($buffer, $str) !== FALSE) {
                return '<pre>'.$matches[] = $buffer.'</pre>';
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Since my `$str` (needle) is an array, I am using `foreach()` to process all its elements and invoke the function every time:

```
foreach ($my_array as $a_match) {
    echo getLineWithString($myFile, trim($a_match));
}
```

However, this approach (using `foreach()`) hits the **max_execution_time**, **memory_limit**, Apache's **FcgidIOTimeout** and others. My array (needle) contains 88 elements and they might grow in number depending on the enduser's actions so this is definitely not an adequate way.

My question is how can I prevent the usage of `foreach()` or any other looping and invoke the function only once?

Comment: if it was me i would call grep, with exec

Comment: @nogad: I usually tend to run away from "mixed"/partial solutions that involve another language.

Comment: "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"

Comment: This is not a memory leak. Memory leaks are what happen when a process allocates memory on the system that is no longer reachable by the process. It is impossible for you PHP code to do this since it has no direct control over memory management, the PHP memory manager does. Your code runs inside the PHP virtual machine so it cannot possibly leak memory. This is why it can be subject to a **memory_limit** in the first place. You inform PHP when to stop allocating memory because it is responsible for controlling and managing your PHP code's memory for you.

Comment: you should use `'\b('.implode( '|', $str ) . ')\b'` and preg_match_all instead of your foreach, and match all the stuff in one call, instead of loading the file multiple times.  Or come up with another strategy that dose so.  Likely you are outpacing the GC.

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix: Could you please PoC that in an answer so I can accept it eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Note about memory leak

It's important to note that this is a misuse of the term *memory leak* since in PHP you have no control over memory management. A memory leak is generally defined as a process having allocated memory on the system that is no longer reachable by that process. It's not possible for you to do this in your PHP code since you have no direct control over the PHP memory manager.

Your code runs inside of the PHP virtual machine which manages memory for you. Exceeding the `memory_limit` you set in PHP is not the same thing as PHP **leaking** memory. This is a defined limit, controlled by you. You can raise or lower this limit at your discretion. You may even [ask PHP to not limit the amount of memory at all](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) by setting `memory_limit = -1`, for example. Of course, this is still subject to your machine's memory capacity.

## Your actual problem

However, the approach you are using is not much better than reading the entire file into memory because you will have to read the file line by line with every search (call to your function). That's worse time complexity even though it may be more efficient in terms of memory.

To be efficient in both time and memory complexity you need to perform the search on each needle at once while reading from the file. Rather than send a *single* needle to your function, consider sending the entire array of needles at once. This way you defer the loop you're using to call your function to the function itself.

Additionally, you should note that your current function returns immediately, upon finding a match, since you're using `return` inside your loop. You should instead use `return $matches` at the end of your function, outside of the loop.

Here's a better approach.

```
function getLineWithString($fileName, Array $needles) {

    $matches = [];
    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");

    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fgets($handle);

            foreach($needles as $str) {
                if (strpos($buffer, $str) !== FALSE) {
                    $matches[] = $buffer;
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
        return $matches;
    }

}
```

Now, let's say you're searching for the strings `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"` in your file. You can make a single call to your function with an array of those strings to search them all at once rather than call your function in a loop. The function will loop over the search strings each time it reads a line from the file and search that `$buffer` for a match, then return the entire `$matches` array when it's done.

```
var_dump(getLineWithStrings("somefile.txt", ["foo", "bar", "baz"]));
```

#### N.B

I'd strongly advice against using the [error silence operator `@`](http://php.net/@) since it will effectively make debugging your code when there is a problem more difficult, because it turns off all error reporting for its operand. Even if there was an error PHP won't tell you about it, which isn't useful at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still run into an `Internal Server Error (500)` as I hit a 60 seconds of execution time. The file I am parsing is just 300 MB.

Comment: I doubt that this code is taking more than 60 seconds to read 300 MB. The issue is likely something else you're doing in your code that's also taking a lot of time.

Comment: I have no other operations except a `trim()` with `array_map()` on all elements before I pass the array to the function. Anyway, thank you for your time. I accepted the answer since it does answer my original question.

Comment: A good place to start is to read the error message and all of the valuable information it gives you on how to debug this problem. For example, the error will tell you on exactly what line of code in which script the timeout occurred. This might be a good place to start looking. Did the timeout occur in this function? If not, where did it occur?

Comment: This is what takes up the most of time: http://pastebin.com/raw/kfg5qpTa . Apparently, `strpos()` is the issue but I don't get why.

Comment: Well, because you're calling strpos `N` times for every `K` lines in your file. So 88 needles in a file made up of a million lines, requires 88 million calls to strpos. If the time complexity is the biggest concern it might suit you better to just raise your memory limit, read the entire file into memory, and only call strpos 88 times instead of 88 million times. (_note that the 1 million lines is an arbitrary number, I have no idea how many lines are actually in your file_). 300MB is really nothing in terms of memory.

Comment: Typically you either sacrifice some extra memory to save yourself a lot of CPU time, or you sacrifice a lot of CPU time to save yourself some memory, but you ultimately hit a curve there. There's only so much you can tradeoff in CPU for memory and only so much memory you can tradeoff for CPU. Try increasing the size of the buffer with consideration of the equation `O(n*k)` ;)

Comment: At first I thought PHP would have no issues working with files of that size but it seems I was wrong. The files I need to process can reach up to 1 GB and 3 million lines at most. I will consider getting rid of PHP's handling of the file and do a `grep` with `shell_exec()`;

Comment: PHP can handle it just fine. The issue is with your code and configuration, not with PHP. For example, if you raised your `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` you wouldn't see any complaints from PHP unless your server runs out of memory. Wanting to do this with a more efficient use of resources, however, is the programmer's responsibility, not PHP's. That goes for **any programming language** by the way.